# Get PyCharm to do auto-suggest when importing packages defined in the project

Tags: python, autocomplete, ide, autosuggest, pycharm

Is there a way to have PyCharm to auto-completion when specifying imports of packages defined in the project?

PyCharm seems to do auto-complete just fine for library packages, but not the ones that have been defined in the project.

Example project structure:

```
ProjectName
 > src
   > package_1
     __init__.py
     package_file.py
   __init__.py
   source_1.py
```

If within the file 'source_1.py', I type the following, I get not auto-suggest for the rest of the work 'package_1':

```
from packa
```

Comment: Is src defined as the project root in your project settings? Maybe project root is not the exact term, but I'm talking about the "blue folders"  (as opposed to the red ones for excluded).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in `Project` sidebar:

right-click on desired folder (`src` in this case) and from context menu choose  `Mark directory as` -> `Source root`. It will turn blue.